# Dynamically changing sidebar width based on an input

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is there anyway to dynamically change the sidebar width based on an input value? In the example below, I would like the width of the sidebar to be based on the `sidebarWidth` input:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 230),
  dashboardBody(
    numericInput("sidebarWith", "Select Sidebar Width", min = 300, max = 500, value = 230)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try the following. Use `uiOutput` in your `ui` to dynamically change in the `server` with `renderUI`. Note that I corrected the spelling of `sidebarWidth` in the example.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = uiOutput("sidebar"),
  body = dashboardBody(
    numericInput("sidebarWidth", "Select Sidebar Width", min = 300, max = 500, value = 230)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$sidebar <- renderUI({
    dashboardSidebar(width = input$sidebarWidth)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this fast, responsive, no server code version, pure Javascript.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(width = 230),
    dashboardBody(
        numericInput("sidebarWith", "Select Sidebar Width", min = 230, max = 500, value = 230),
        tags$script(HTML(
        '
        $(function(){
            var mainContent = $(".wrapper > .content-wrapper");
            var curWidth = 230;
            $("#sidebarWith").on("change", function() {
                if(parseFloat($(this).val()) < 230 || parseFloat($(this).val()) > 500) {return false}
                curWidth = $(this).val();
                mainContent.css("margin-left", `${curWidth}px`);
                $(".main-header .navbar").css("margin-left", `${curWidth}px`);
                $(".main-header .logo").css("width", `${curWidth}px`);
            });
            $(".sidebar-toggle").on("click", function() {
                if(!$("body").hasClass("sidebar-collapse")) {
                    mainContent.css("margin-left", `0px`);
                    $(".main-header .navbar").css("margin-left", `0px`);
                    $(".main-header .logo").css("width", `0px`);
                } else {
                    mainContent.css("margin-left", `${curWidth}px`);
                    $(".main-header .navbar").css("margin-left", `${curWidth}px`);
                    $(".main-header .logo").css("width", `${curWidth}px`);
                }
            })
        });
        '
        ))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

1. No server code is needed. Apply the UI, server separation design: If we can solve the problem by only using the UI, do it in UI. UI only solutions generally have better performance and speed than UI-server communication.
2. I noticed there is a button on the top to collapse the sidebar, so I made changes accordingly. When you click it, it will collapse and resume to the right width you set in the numeric input.
3. Original header left is not collapsed when you click the collapse button, and its width is not changed. I made it align with the width of the sidebar and made it collapse as well when you click the button.

[image]